# Trigger Bootstrap dropdown with external action

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get this dropdown to fire when I click the text link. When I click the link, it writes the CORRECT element ID `dropdownMenuButton2` to the console, but it actually triggers `dropdownMenuButton1`.

```js
$('.dd').on('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log('trying to trigger '+id);
  $('#'+id).dropdown('toggle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   
<button type="button" class="dd" id="dropdownMenuButton2">click me</button>
   
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

- -

Comment: Don't assign the same `id` to multiple elements. In your `dd` button, use `data-id="dropdownMenuButton2"`, then use `var id = $(this).data('id');`

Comment: Oops, didn't even notice I'd done this! Post as an answer and I'll select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is

```
<button type="button" class="dd" id="dropdownMenuButton2">click me</button>
```

and the dropdown

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

has duplicate ids. if you store "dropdownMenuButton2" in data attribute, it would solve the issue.

```
<button type="button" class="dd" data="dropdownMenuButton2">click me</button>

$('.dd').on('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var id = $(this).attr('data');
  console.log('trying to trigger '+id);
  $('#'+id).dropdown('toggle');
});
```